# angular-cli 3rd Party Library - jquery.floatThead 2.0.3

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I want to use floatThead in my Angular2 app.
I have install jquery as a global library.

In angular-cli.json

```
"scripts": ["../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
              "../node_modules/ngx-rating/ngx-rating.pure.amd.js",
              "../node_modules/bootstrap-select/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js",
              "../node_modules/floatthead/dist/jquery.floatThead.min.js"
              ],
```

In the component I have imported both jquery and floatThead as follows

```
    import * as $ from 'jquery';
    import * as floatThead from 'floatThead';
    ...
    $('card-list-table').floatThead({top:110,
        responsiveContainer: function($table){ 
            return $table.closest(".table-responsive");
        }
    });
```

There is no complitaion issue but I am getting this runtime error and plugin doesn't work

```
ERROR TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5_jquery__(...).floatThead is not a function
    at CustomerListComponent.webpackJsonp.../../../../../src/app/
```

It looks even I have imported jquery globally it has an issue jquery plugins getting loaded.

Can someone please suggest whats wrong in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting the same Error.

Here how did I solve the issue.

- First of all I did remove both JQuery and floatThead from angular-cli.json "imports"
- Second, I have imported both jquery and floatThead as follows

> import * as $ from 'jquery'
>
> import 'floatThead'

And now in my Component ***ngOnInit*** it works as expected.

```
ngOnInit() {
    $(this.el.nativeElement).floatThead({top:40,
      responsiveContainer: ($table) => {
        debugger
        return $table.closest(".table-responsive");
      }
    }); 
}
```

**NOTE**:  If you are using **typescript** please make sure to add an interface for **floatThead**.

It can be done as follows

Go to your **typings.d.ts** and add

```
interface JQuery {
  floatThead(options?: any) : any;
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Your solution worked for me but I cannot remove jquery since bootstrap requires jquery and it gives error if I remove it. Any other solution?

Comment: I am using bootstrap as well without including both bootsrap as well as jquery explicitly under angular-cli.json.

Comment: You can include bootsrap into your project differently.

This should be helpful.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50290197/how-to-add-bootstrap-in-angular-6-project.  Let me know if I can help more. Thanks.