# How to add bootstrap in angular 6 project?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

[image: app.component.html]

[image: index.html]

[image: app.component.ts]

I have tried to add styles dependency in `angular.json` package but showing that the module not found. adding two of the bootstrap files.
here is the screenshot of both the files

the angular.json file is like this [angular.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqIy0.png)

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: @Phil I doubt it's not duplicate OP is unaware of the angular version he is using, he has mentioned about `angular.json` file which is used in angular 6

Comment: @phil no i am using angular 2 only in it also the previous angular-cli.json  file is renamed as angular.json .

Comment: @Phil after adding jquery library and compiled java script and importing bootstrap.min.css in app.component.css  its bootstraping but the  container class  is not working

Comment: but the ng version (angular cli  )shows it to be  6.0.0

Comment: @nikhilsugandh You are not supposed to import it in app.component.css; you are supposed to import it in assets/style.css or assets/styles.scss (depending on whether you use sass or not)

Comment: @phil though i dont have style.css in asset i created one its ok ???

Comment: @nikhilsugandh as long as you have `"styles": ["assets/styles.css"]` in your angular.json

Comment: This is not a duplicate as the compared questions is about Angular 2, whereas this questions is for Angular 6 and the correct response is slightly different due to changes in versions and best practices to apply css styles.

Comment: Voted to reopen this question. It is not a duplicate as Angular 2 and 6 are very different beasts.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

## For Angular Version 11+

**Configuration**

The styles and scripts options in your angular.json configuration now allow to reference a package directly:

before: `"styles": ["../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"]`
after: `"styles": ["bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"]`

```
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/ng6",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css","bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

            ],
            "scripts": [
                       "jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                       "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                       ]
          },
```

## Angular Version 10 and below

You are using Angular v6 not 2

> **Angular v6 Onwards**

CLI projects in angular 6 onwards will be using  `angular.json` instead of `.angular-cli.json` for build and project configuration.

Each CLI workspace has projects, each project has targets, and each target can have configurations.**[Docs](https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4)**

```
. {
  "projects": {
    "my-project-name": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "configurations": {
            "production": {},
            "demo": {},
            "staging": {},
          }
        },
        "serve": {},
        "extract-i18n": {},
        "test": {},
      }
    },
    "my-project-name-e2e": {}
  },
}
```

**OPTION-1**
execute `npm install bootstrap@4 jquery --save`
The JavaScript parts of `Bootstrap` are dependent on `jQuery`. So you need the `jQuery` `JavaScript` library file too.

In your angular.json  add the file paths  to the styles and scripts array in under `build` target
**NOTE:**
Before v6 the Angular CLI project configuration was stored in `<PATH_TO_PROJECT>/.angular-cli.json.` As of v6 the location of the file changed to `angular.json.` Since there is no longer a leading dot, the file is no longer hidden by default and is on the same level.

which also means that file paths in angular.json should not contain leading dots and slash

> i.e you can provide an absolute path instead of a relative path

In `.angular-cli.json` file Path was `"../node_modules/"`
In `angular.json` it is `"node_modules/"`

```
 "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/ng6",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css","node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
               
            ],
            "scripts": ["node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                       "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"]
          },
```

**OPTION 2** 
Add files from CDN (Content Delivery Network) to your project **[CDN LINK](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/#bootstrapcdn)**

Open file src/index.html and insert

the `<link>` element at the end of the head section to include the Bootstrap CSS file
a `<script>` element to include jQuery at the bottom of the body section
a `<script>` element to include Popper.js  at the bottom of the body section
a `<script>` element to include the Bootstrap JavaScript file at the bottom of the body section

```
  <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Angular</title>
      <base href="/">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
      <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**OPTION 3** 
Execute `npm install bootstrap`
In `src/styles.css`  add the following line:

`@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";`

**OPTION-4**
**[ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started)** It contains a set of native Angular directives based on Bootstrap’s markup and CSS. As a result, it's not dependent on jQuery or Bootstrap’s JavaScript

```
npm install --save @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

After Installation import it in your root module and register it in `@NgModule` imports` array

```
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, ...],
  imports: [NgbModule.forRoot(), ...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

**NOTE**
`ng-bootstrap` requires Bootstrap's 4 css to be added in your project. you need to Install it explicitly via:
`npm install bootstrap@4  --save`
In your angular.json  add the file paths  to the styles array in under `build` target

```
   "styles": [
      "src/styles.css",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
   ],
```

### P.S Do Restart Your server

`ng serve || npm start`

Comment: the simple bootstrap is working but the container class bootstrap isnt

Comment: That should not be the case create a stackblitz without code i cant' help you

Comment: you have already added bootstrap in your `angular.json` the links and script in your `index.html` is redundant and see if it works

Comment: I checked alternatively changing in angular.json does not implement bootstrap  but the three tags in index.html worked perfectly.

Comment: My issue was the leading './' it's a simple step to miss

Comment: Don't forget to re-start 'ng serve'

Comment: First install bootstrap in project directory `npm install bootstrap`. If you look at the Angular.JSON file you will see that styles.css is already referenced so in styles.css just add `@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";`

Comment: @skydev what about the features of `bootstrap` which are dependent on `jquery` and `javascript` Those have to be added in `scripts` array

Comment: @Vikas that's what ng-bootstrap and ngx-bootstrap take care of. You do not need jquery.

Comment: @Seiyria   have i not mentioned the same in the answer?

Comment: @Vikas it should not even be part of the answer.

Comment: @Seiyria I disagree Since it's community-wide accepted and it also includes the alternative to bootstrap I would not alter it. :)

Comment: @Vikas you're welcome to disagree, but no angular2+ solution involving jQuery is "community-wide" accepted. jQuery greatly interferes with how angular2+ handles the DOM and causes more headaches than not.

Comment: You can now use: ng add @ng-bootstrap/schematics
From the ng workspace folder, this will add ng-bootstrap which does not require jquery and popper, even tough you get a working saying they are missing.
The team that works on ng-bootstrap tries to keep the same browser compatibility, this is the easiest way (my opinion) so far.

Comment: option 3 works for me

Comment: @KamilNaja exactly, **option 3** works fine me too even without restarting the server BUT the **option** 1 requires server **restart** (`ng s`) before it works. :)

Answer (score 11):

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

afterwards, inside `angular.json` (previously `.angular-cli.json`) inside the project's root folder, find styles and add the bootstrap css file like this:

for angular 6

```
"styles": [
          "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "styles.css"
],
```

for angular 7

```
"styles": [
          "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.css"
],
```

Comment: Does this automatically include the other stuff, like bootstrap-grid, etc ?

Comment: for older specific version: npm install bootstrap@3.3.7 --save

Answer (score 6):

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

and add relevent files into `angular.json` file under the `style` property for css files and under `scripts` for JS files.

```
 "styles": [
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
   ....
]
```

Comment: is `--save` still required? I guess i somewhere read that it is not required if you're using npm > v5.

Comment: Nope, you still need to add `--save` in order to update `.package.json` as per my knowledge

Comment: if all that `--save` does is add a dependency to `package.json` then I can confirm it is not required if using npm v5.6.0. Just confirmed that on test angular project. :-)

Comment: Ohh that is great if so, haven't tried yet !!

Comment: yeah, but other options like `--save-dev` and the other one for optional dependency would still require explicit flag.

Comment: Can you please provide any documentation for the same?

Comment: If you go `npm install -h`, and check the bottom section of the help, common options listed there are`--save-prod | --save-dev | --save-optional` on top of this, there is `--no-save`, i assume `--no-save` would prevent the default behavior of adding package to `package.json`.

Comment: jquery is required?

Comment: @SunilGarg its upto your requirement. 
PS: As per community using jQuery with angular is not a recommended approach.

Comment: @PardeepJain, yes its not recommended, thats why i asked is jquery is required to use bootstrap?

Comment: no, its not required you can use standalone UI file of the bootstrap as well, but some of the bootstrap widget requires JQuery in use internally so keep in mind if you are using any of them.

Answer (score 3):

using command

```
npm install bootstrap --save
```

open **.angular.json**  old ***(.angular-cli.json )*** file find the "styles" add the bootstrap css file

```
"styles": [
       "src/styles.scss",
       "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
```