# use bootstrap 3 in angular 6

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, angular6

how i can use bootstrab 3 in angular 6 ?? it's not work in any way , i used :

```
npm install bootstrap@3 jquery --save
```

then update angular.json as follow :

```
"styles": [
          "src/styles.css",
          "../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"

        ],
        "scripts": [
          "../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
```

in html bootstrap class appear , but it dosen't work !! it's git this error

```
91% additional asset processing scripts-webpack-plugin× ｢wdm｣: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.min.js'
```

Comment: path to node modules may be wrong , i think it should "../node_modules"

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oyxshp?file=src/index.html   for reference

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50294196/5695162)

Answer (score 2):

INSTALL BOOTSTRAP (All bootstrap installed in node_module folder)

```
npm install bootstrap@3 jquery --save
```

Angular.json file

Add styles and scripts file to Angular.json for globalise

```
"styles": [
    "src/styles.css",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
]
```

component.html

```
<a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="" role="button">View</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, update your node_modules location as below

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
```

code sample - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oyxshp?file=angular.json

Comment: its still git this error :  91% additional asset processing scripts-webpack-plugin× ｢wdm｣: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'E:\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.min.js'

Comment: any other console errors apart form the above and also could you share errors before from console

Comment: any luck @ammarammary

Answer (score 0):

i solve it

```js
"styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
```