# Integrating Bootstrap3 Theme with Angular7

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-themes

I am working on a project where I am building a UI and the theme selected for it is a bit old and is made in bootstrap 3.x and has support only for angularjs and not angular 4+. But it is apt and we like it and so selected it.

I have searched around and got many tutorials on how to integrate bootstrap with Angular but they really don't address the details like,

1. Will the theme require the basic bootstrap3 css and js files as well or will it run just by using its own js and css?
2. What about the other libraries that the theme might use? like the fonts, charting, displaying progress etc could come from other js files. How do we pull in these dependencies into the angular 7 cli based project.
3. Is there some automation available or does it have to be done manually?

What is the best way to go about integrating such a theme? are there any other concerns we need to take care of?

It would be great if someone can give an example of how to integrate a bs3.x theme with angular7.

Comment: Why use 3 instead of 4?

Comment: Because the creator of the theme doesn't have a version built on BS 4 and angular 4+. Also I am more worried about the fact that it wont follow the components based design that angular follows. That why this query how to make older themes without Angular support work on newer angular versions. Hope it made sense. Edited the question for more clarity.

Comment: You need to find another theme. Or make your own, it isn’t very difficult.

Comment: Take a look at this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50380019/use-bootstrap-3-in-angular-6 You can add the required css and is references to angular.json.