# Adding a jQuery component to Angular 6

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-cli

I'm having problems embedding a jQuery cascading dropdown component to my Angular 6 project.  I got an error when attempting to run `ng serve`:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   C:\nodeprojects\node_modules\jquery\dist\jquery.min.js.

Here are the steps I took to add jQuery to Angular 6:

1. Ran

`npm install jquery`

' and verified `jquery.min.js` was in that path listed above.

2. Modified `angular.json` (Angular 6 no longer has an 'angular-cli.json' file) and added the relative path to the `jquery.min.js` file in the 'scripts []' section.
3. I'm using `app.component` as the target component.  In `app.component.ts`, I entered, `declare var $: any;` and entered the jquery custom component function inside `export class AppComponent implements OnInit()`.

The jquery component I am trying to embed into Angular is located at https://jsfiddle.net/brohjoe/zgc0n1q5/1/

The HTML was entered into `app.component.html`. I deleted references to the script src because the minified jquery library was listed in `angular.json` as mentioned and the custom.js code was embedded in `app.component.ts` as mentioned above.

After running localhost:4200, the only ui elements that will display are the dropdowns with no data.

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50294196/5695162)

Comment: Thank you Vikas.  That site helped.  I had two leading dots in the path to the jQuery library, but the node_modules directory and the angular.json file are on the same level, so removing the leading dots fixed the problem.  Compiled with no errors!

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you upgraded the latest Angular CLI version. To check, run ng --version command.

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
```

To download Bootstrap package in your project node_modules, use this command. It will also include related jQuery.

```
npm install --save bootstrap
```

or simply jQuery

```
npm install jquery --save
```

No look for "Angular.json" file and edit this script under "Projects:{...}" like bellow:

```
    "styles": [
      "src/styles.css",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    ],
    "scripts": [
      "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
      "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
    ]
```

Then you can import jquery file into your app.module.ts file like the way:

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

After all done above those tasks, If you have same error, check your "package.json" file to make sure whether packages are installed.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to load a customized jquery-ui.min.js located in my src folder via "scripts": ["src/jquery-ui.min.js"] of angular.json like [OPTION 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50290197/how-to-add-bootstrap-in-angular-6-project/50294196#50294196) suggests, but for some angular routing configurations this doesn't work (see [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11044)).

In this case [OPTION 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50290197/how-to-add-bootstrap-in-angular-6-project/50294196#50294196) works: add the script with an **absolute url as script tag** to the body of your **src/index.html** file.

Answer (score 0):

Refering following Link: [Medium.com - How to include and use jQuery in Angular CLI project](https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/how-to-include-and-use-jquery-in-angular-cli-project-592e0fe63176)

**Answer for Angular 4+ application.**

First install jQuery using npm as follows

```
npm install jquery — save
```

Second go to the `angular.json` file at the root of your Angular CLI project folder, and find the scripts: [] property, and include the path to jQuery as follows

```
"scripts": [ "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ]
```

Note: If you want to use bootstrap or https://materializecss.com in your application or if you already have in your project.

**make sure to include jQuery before including the bootstrap javascript file as follows. Since bootstrap’s and Materializecss javascript file requires jQuery.**

I have used Materializecss and also added `CSS` file into style.

```
       "styles": [
          "./node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": ["./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "./node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js"]
```