# How do you install bootstrap and popper.js on the command line in angular. I keep getting errors when I run ng-serve and try to open up the app

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, command-line-interface, font-awesome, popper.js

When I run ng serve and try to open up my app, it says that there is an error and the app cant find bootstrap or popper.js. I put code in my angular.json file in the scripts and styles tag. Can someone please help me? thanks!

this is the code that i try to put into the angular.json file on the app:

```
  "styles": [


 "src/styles.css",
              "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css",
              "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.js",
              "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ],
```

Comment: Try `./`instead of `../`, though pretty sure you don't even need to do `./` just `node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js` should be fine.

Comment: did you run npm install? do those node_modules folders exist?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add bootstrap in angular 6 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50290197/how-to-add-bootstrap-in-angular-6-project)