# Bootstrap version 3.4 not working in Angular 9

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have installed bootstrap version 3.4 using Angular cli. Below is the command I used 
    npm install --save bootstrap@3
Then I have added

```
"styles": [
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
          "src/styles.css"
        ],
        "scripts": [
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        ]
```

In angular.json file.
But I am unable to access the bootstrap default style class. No bootstrap file is showing in browser console whenever I run the application.

I am unable to find the issue here. Your help would be greatly appreciated. 
Adding screenshot of my node_modules folder
[image: node_modules]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add bootstrap in angular 6 project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50290197/how-to-add-bootstrap-in-angular-6-project)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

to src/styles file.

Answer (score 1):

Your paths shouldn't start with a `./`.

Instead, try the following:

```
"styles": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
  "src/styles.css"
],
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  ]
```

This now makes them relative to the project root.

Working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-etn2fd

Comment: I have tried this also, that was not working either.

Comment: Have you navigated to the mode_modules folder to make sure the file is there?

Comment: Yes I have checked that as well.

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding the app after updating those paths?

Comment: Yes I did that.

Comment: I've created a working demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-etn2fd. Can you recreate the problem in a stackblitz?

Comment: Sorry here I am unable to reproduce as your bootstrap is working fine. But mine not working :(

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to your question of the file in the bootstrap node_modules folder, including the path

Comment: When I import the bootstrap.min.css file in style.css, it started working.

Answer (score 1):

Remove relative path use like below. As src is used directly just like that use node_modules not ./node_modules

```
"styles": [

              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
```

A good resource link is

https://medium.com/@oyewusioyekunle/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-your-angular-project-angular-8-6379fd6a0f46